# Can you resize partition that Windows C: is on without deleting Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a HDD that has only 1 partition (if you don't count 500MB system reserved). That one partition is Windows C:. It is only 30% used. I've been wanting to install Linux somewhere and maybe dual boot would be a good option for me. So I would need to resize that partition in order to be able to dual boot. Are tools like MiniTool Partition Wizard (which has "resize" option) or GParted able to do what I want with 100% certainty that my Windows partition won't get deleted? Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind me making a friendly recommendation:  you should consider installing Linux into a VM using a free hypervisor (VirtualBox or Hyper-V) within your Windows operating system.  We see a **lot** of questions posted in Super User from people who attempt to configure a Windows/Linux dual-boot configuration and encounter a wide range of problems.

Comment: gparted will do what you want.  It will not by itself delete your windows partition.  However, if you use it incorrectly it could do anything.  Like a hammer, can be used to pound in a nail, or smash things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can do that for sure, actually you don't even need external tools you could do it with Windows itself
1- Press Windows+R

2- Write "diskmgmt.msc" ( without the quotation marks)

This will open up the disk management in windows.

3- Right click on partition C and choose shrink.

4- specify partition size, the left space will be "unallocated" space.

5- Right click on the newly formed unallocated space

6-Right-click the unallocated volume.

7-Choose New Simple Volume from the shortcut menu.

8- Set the size of the new volume by using the Simple Volume Size in MB text box.

9-Click the Next button.

10- Quickly format it and then Click the Finish button to create the new volume.

just so you know this method might not always work because sometimes windows keep unmovable files on the C drive (files belong to 3 services windows uses) if you want to use this method you will have to disable these three services (Hibernation, Pagefile and System protection) and do the shrinking process then re-enable them again.

However you can skip that mess and use any partition manager software and it will do the resizing work well.

Comment: Um no, Windows isn't going to let you resize its own system volume while it's in use.

Comment: hmm, I just tried it the other day though, I had only one drive (C:) and I needed to make it into two partitions, at first it didn't allow it because the unmovable files I mentioned above, however after disabling them it allowed me to shrink it freely. You can read more about it here : [link] (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)  and  here [link] (http://www.disk-partition.com/articles/shrink-volume-with-unmovable-files-4348.html)

Comment: Even if that is possible, it's certainly not recommended. There would be files open all over the place and you are asking for trouble. Changed partitions whilst they are offline is MUCH safer.

Comment: @Darren It is possible to do, but only in Windows 10, and the server equivalent.  However, it will limit your ability to resize to the location of the furthest file.  If you have a file 50% into the free space that is your limit.

Comment: @cybernard it is possible even in Windows Vista check out the screenshots from this article [link] (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) 
@ Darren  as Cybernard said you won't be able to shrink the partition as you wish, in the first place if it prevented you from shrinking it that's because Windows cannot the three files I mentioned above, the rest is movable, again you would probably be able to shrink it to 50% as cybernard mentioned.

Comment: @Darren This has been possible since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows system partition can only be resized offline, i.e. When Windows isn't running.

Most Linux installation CDs include the option to resize the existing windows partition to make room for Linux during the installation process. There is usually a bunch of standard options like "wipe disk and use all space for Linux", "resize existing partition and use x% of disk space for Linux" and then advanced options where you can manipulate the partition sizes yourself with GParted or similar.

The changes you make don't take affect until you hit Apply and there is usually a stern warning before it happens so you should be able to safely experiment with different options but it's best to just let the installer do its thing with one of the preset basic options.

It's fairly straight forward, but never 100% guaranteed safe. Only do this if you have a backup of important data and you have a Windows installation or recovery disk to get your system back on its feet.